# C# declaring class with string called 'type' causes extremely weird compile issues

Tags: c#, class, variables, types, member

I can't quite explain this but perhaps someone can see something I can't. If I try to declare the following class and use it, this is all I get in my output after a clean and rebuild all:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3647,5): error MSB3027: Could not copy "obj\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe" to "bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.

The Class:

```
    public class cDescriptions
{
    public string appid { get; set; }
    public string classid { get; set; }
    public string instanceid { get; set; }
    public string icon_url { get; set; }
    public string icon_url_large { get; set; }
    public string icon_drag_url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string market_hash_name { get; set; }
    public string market_name { get; set; }
    public string name_color { get; set; }
    public string background_color { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int tradable { get; set; }
    public int marketable { get; set; }
    public int commodity { get; set; }
    public string market_fee_app { get; set; }
    public string market_tradable_restriction { get; set; }
    public string market_marketable_restriction { get; set; }
}
```

However, renaming public string type { get; set; } to say m_type, or even just changing its position in the class declaration causes it to compile and run perfectly. I really don't understand why this is happening?

As a simple test I created a class with a string called 'type' and it worked fine which ruled out 'type' being some sort of special keyword.

Weird! Any ideas why this happens? It doesn't even catch it at compile time, it just failes to copy the .exe after it has finished compiling!

(I'm on Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2013 Update 5)

Comment: Usually this happen because the output file is locked, probably because the application is still running when you recompile it.

Comment: "Exceeded retry count" normally means that the .exe is in use, maybe running unit tests / not closed correctly / still has a file pointer open especially if you open any images.  Try doing 'clean solution' first, then building and see what happens.

Comment: Wait, you can't even repro and still you ask this?  Look, sometimes during compile a file can't be overwritten because something is locking it.  Happens sometimes.  Nothing to do with a string called type.  This is all a logical fallacy--just because A happens before B doesn't mean A caused B.

Comment: If I open up a brand new C# Windows Form project and declare this class in the way I've posted it, it will fail with the same error as above. The not being able to copy the .exe seems like some weird red herring because it definitely isn't locked or still open. Changing the variable name of the 'type' string makes it compile and work perfectly.

Comment: Add an exclusion for your project directory in your anti-malware product.  If it is Avast then get rid of it completely.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah Thanks so much! Disabled avast and it compiled. Wow, Avast didn't even tell me it was interfering or anything! Any tips for a good alternative haha?

Comment: Close voters: IMHO this question should stay here, now that we know the cause and the fix. Other developers might have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)

> Add an exclusion for your project directory in your anti-malware product.